# Hello, how do I bulk remove members sorted by Teams names?

Tags: azure, powershell, office365, microsoft-teams

I have the following code but unfortunately I am stuck with the -user parameter for remove-azureaduser, it comes back as resource does not exist, any powershell expert willing to help?

Edit: The idea here was that it would work with multiple teams names as well

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams

$Teams = Get-Team -DisplayName "test"

$users = Get-TeamUser -GroupId $Teams.GroupId -Role Member | Select-Object user

Foreach ($user in $users) {

Remove-TeamUser -GroupId $Teams.GroupId -User $user

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Docu: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/remove-teamuser?view=teams-ps

As I dont have this cmdlets I can't really verify but I think this is wrong:

```
$users = Get-TeamUser -GroupId $Teams.GroupId -Role Member | Select-Object user
```

Select-Object user? Think this does not work, based on the documentation u need to provide the userPrincipalName to the cmdlet Remove-TeamUser and I don't think the object returned by the Get-teamUser cmdlet has a property called user.

Simply do this:

```
$teams #array containing n teams
foreach ($team in $teams){
    $users = Get-TeamUser -GroupId $Team.GroupId -Role Member
    Foreach ($user in $users) {
        Remove-TeamUser -GroupId $Team.GroupId -User $user.userPrincipalName
    }
}
```

I don't know if the attribute is called userPrincipalName or UPN... just output one user ($user[0]) to see the list of available attributes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately, I am looking to make it work for multiple Teams, do you think this is possible?

Comment: should be just one loop more, i updated the code sample. There is assume that $teams is a array containing the several teams...

Comment: Thank you, I'll update as soon as I can try it out

Comment: Very close but it's stuck on Remove-TeamUser, namely Remove-TeamUser : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'GroupId'.

Comment: sorry for the late feedback... jepp I see - I'll update the code ;-)

Comment: Thank you, I'll be waiting patiently :)

Comment: hehe, you dont have to I did update the code on the same day ;-) I did a typo $teams.groupid -> $team.groupId - this version works or?

Comment: With a few adjustments posted in the original, it worked, thanks Tony!

Comment: @user19929167 I did approve your edits but this version makes no sense anymore hrhr, idk what went wrong

Comment: i switched back, sorry - feel free to edit again and I will avoid to change anything - like formatting

Comment: I tried putting the answer in the question as an edit, which didn't work i guess. I've added it as an answer, the only adjustment I still did was for $user.user.

Answer (score 0):

After a small adjustmend, the answer is, thanks to Tony:

```
$Teams = Get-Team -DisplayName "test"

$users = Get-TeamUser -GroupId $Teams.GroupId -Role Member

foreach ($team in $teams){

    $users = Get-TeamUser -GroupId $Team.GroupId -Role Member

    Foreach ($user in $users) {

        Remove-TeamUser -GroupId $Team.GroupId -User $user.User

    }

}
```